# Checking for availability of Atlas with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

We are creating a NodeJS based solution that makes use of MongoDB, by means of Mongoose. We recently started adding support for Atlas, but we would like to be able to fallback to non-Atlas based queries, when Atlas is not available, for a given connection.

I can't assume the software will be using MongoDB Cloud. Although I could make assumptions based on the URL, I'd still need to have a way to be able to do something like:

```
const available: boolean = MyModel.connection.isAtlasAvailable()
```

The reason we want this is because if we make an assumption on Atlas being available and then the client uses a locally hosted MongoDB, the following code will break, since `$search` is Atlas specific:

```
const results = await Person.aggregate([
  {
    $search: {
      index: 'people_text_index',
      deleted: { $ne: true },
      'text': {
        'query': filter.query,
        'path': {
          wildcard: '*'
        }
      },
      count: {
        type: 'total'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      'mongoMeta': '$$SEARCH_META'
    }
  },
  { $skip : offset },
  { $limit: limit }
]);
```

I suppose I could surround this with a try/catch and then fall back to a non-Atlas search, but I'd rather check something is doable before trying an operation.

Is there any way to check whether MongoDB Atlas is available, for a given connection? As an extension to the question, does Mongoose provide a general pattern for checking for feature availability, such as if the connection supports transactions?

Comment: What are you referring to by non atlas base queries? It's either connected/disconnected to Atlas right? Mongoose does not check for feature availability, you can use `try/catch` blocks.

Comment: MongoDB Atlas is a cloud service. As long as you have internet connection the probability is very high that it is available.

Comment: I might need to go with the try/catch approach, if there is no other solution - I have update the question to suggest this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose I could surround this with a try/catch and then fall back to a non-Atlas search, but I'd rather check something is doable before trying an operation.

As an `isAtlasCluster()` check, it would be more straightforward to use a regex match to confirm the hostname in the connection URI ends in `mongodb.net` as used by MongoDB Atlas clusters.

However, it would also be much more efficient to set a feature flag based on the connection URI when your application is initialised rather than using `try`/`catch` within the model on every request (which will add latency of at least one round trip failure for every search request).

I would also note that checking for an Atlas connection is not equivalent to checking if Atlas Search is configured for a collection. If your application requires some initial configuration of search indexes, you may want to have a more explicit feature flag configured by an app administrator or enabled as part of search index creation.

There are a few more considerations depending on the destination cluster tier:

- Atlas [free & shared tier clusters support fewer indexes](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search/limitations/) so a complex application may have a minimum cluster tier requirement.
- Atlas Serverless Instances (currently in preview) does not currently have support for Atlas Search (see [Serverless Instance Limitations](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/serverless-instance-limitations/#capabilities)).

> As an extension to the question, does Mongoose provide a general pattern checking for feature availability, such as if the connection supports transactions?

Multi-document transactions are supported in all non-EOL versions of MongoDB server (4.2+) as long as you are connected to a replica set or sharded cluster deployment using the WiredTiger storage engine (default for new deployments since MongoDB 3.2). MongoDB 4.0 also supports multi-document transactions, but only for replica set deployments using WiredTiger.

If your application has a requirement for multi-document transaction support, I would also check that on startup or make it part of your application deployment prerequisites.

Overall this feels like complexity that should be covered by prerequisites and set up of your application rather than runtime checks which may cause your application to behave unexpectedly even if the initial deployment seems fine.